# How to create the Keystore and trustore jks based on server.pem and certificate.cer format in OpenshiftContainer

Tags: mongodb, openshift, keystore, truststore

I have server.pem and certificate.cer files to connect to MongoDB database in openshift container.

Tried with the below command to convert the server.pem to MongoDB.PKCS12 format and to create the keystore.jks and trustore.jks files in Openshift container.cer format .But getting exception in Openshift container .Could anyone suggest on this please how to resolve the below issue.

Commands:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in C:\server.pem -out C:\mongodb.pkcs12

oc create secret generic keystore --from-file=keystore.jks=C:\mongodb.pkcs12 --from-file=truststore.jks=C:\mongodb.pkcs12 --type=opaque
secret/keystore created

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:525) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:413) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:269) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:106) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_262]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:765) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:410) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1670) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445) ~[na:1.8.0_262]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could anyone help on this please

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create secret more easy. For example:

```
oc create secret generic keystore-volume \
   --from-file=keystore.jks=C:\mongodb.pkcs12 \
   --from-file=truststore.jks=C:\mongodb.pkcs12
```

After that, you can mount this keystore-volume in your application.yaml, like:

```
              ...
              volumeMounts:
            - name: keystore-volume
              mountPath: /app/secrets
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: keystore-volume
          secret:
            secretName: keystore-volume
      ...
```

And your file could available into container by path /app/secrets/mongodb.pkcs12

Comment: :Thank you for your response ,the issue is with the above exception is root certificate needs to be add in Java\JRE8\lib\security\cacerts folder .I am facing an issue how to add root certificate in OpenshiftContainer in Java\JRE8\lib\security\cacerts folder .Could you please assist on how to add root certificate in java cacerts folder in OpenshiftContainer

Comment: This is simple. Just import certificate to cacerts, and then mount you new cacerts file to conteiner like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Yes , we can import the certificate to cacerts but in OpenshiftContainer already cacerts file is existing in Java folder , I have tried to get the Container cacerts file into my local environment but not able to get the Container cacerts file

Comment: Look.. Take cacert from image or container, import cert to this file and then mount new cacert to container when pod is starting.

Comment: ,I have added .cer format to cacert to container but still facing an javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException in OpenshiftContainer .Could you please suggest how to resolve the issue

Comment: Where you mount your cacerts?

Comment: ,I have not add mount for cacerts .Through docker file added .cer format to  container folder cacerts

Comment: Run your docker image go to cli and check certs in cacerts.

Comment: cacert is already having the root certificate but not sure still it is failing with the Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Possible you do not add need certificate. Get certificate againd, add its to the cacerts, and mount how I wrote below.